# The difference between char string[100] and char *string = malloc(100)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

If it does allocate memory why do you not have to free string?

like you would if you did:

```
char *string;
string = malloc(100);
```

Does it perhaps differ in some way because `char[100]` is static and the other way is dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char string[100];` allocates memory as long as the variable lives.

If it is a **static** variable this is as long as the program runs. The variable is allocated statically in the `bss` or `data` segment (or `rodata` or any other segment the compiler-linker-system sees fit.)

If it is a **dynamic** ("automatic" in the C standard) variable this is as long as the containing block runs. The variable is most commonly allocated on the stack and the space is automatically "freed" at the end of the block when the stack pointer is adjusted.

In contrary, if you use `malloc()` the space is commonly allocated on the heap. You have to manage it yourself by giving it back through `free()` if you're done.

So, to answer your question literally, **no**, `char string[100];` does **not** allocate memory through `malloc()`. Therefore there is no need to call `free()` and it will be an error.

Comment: In the C standard, the storage duration of non-static objects without linkage is called “automatic”, not “dynamic”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the answer. The wording is like in the question. :-}